# How to print row index and occurences count of zeros in rows in R data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, row, zero

I want to print row index and the number of zeros present in each row of a R `data.frame` ..

The input matrix is like this:

```
            A    B
rowIndex1   0    1
rowIndex2   1    1
```

I thought to use this:

```
print(which(rowSums(matrix == 0) != 0))
```

I want that it prints something like this:

```
rowIndex1
1
```

However it does not print the number of zeros in the rows but a different number (I checked it) - like this:

```
rowIndex1
2400
```

How to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your `data.frame` looks like and what you want the output to look like? At the moment, it sounds like you might be interested in the `arr.ind` argument to `which`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, perhaps `arr.ind` would be of use.

Using @bartektartanus's sample data:

```
m <- diag(5) + c(0:6,0,0)

table(which(m == 0, arr.ind=TRUE)[, "row"])
# 
# 2 3 4 5 
# 1 2 1 1
```

The "names" (in this case, 2, 3, 4, and 5) are your row numbers and the values (in this case, 1, 2, 1, 1) are the counts.

Here is the output of `which`, so you can understand what is going on:

```
which(m == 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   3   2
# [2,]   4   2
# [3,]   5   2
# [4,]   2   4
# [5,]   3   4
```

Comment: I did a fast check and I did not manage to make it work. Asap I'll check your answer even if the accepted answer has been already marked and it seems quite straightforward. Thanks

Comment: @unsel, I don't quite understand your comment. What part didn't work?

Comment: It worked.. sorry I mistyped something and initially it did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is working good. You get row number that contains zero.

```
> m <- diag(5) + c(0:6,0,0)
Warning message:
In diag(5) + c(0:6, 0, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    1    6    2
[2,]    1    7    2    0    3
[3,]    2    0    4    0    4
[4,]    3    0    4    1    5
[5,]    4    0    5    1    7
> which(rowSums(m == 0) != 0)
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

to obtain what you want use this:

```
> x <- rowSums(m==0)
> cbind(which(x!=0),x[x!=0])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    4    1
[4,]    5    1
```

Comment: It does work.. Can you please explain the part inside `cbind`? I am a noob on `R`

Comment: cbind simply join two (or more) columns together. x!=0 is to accomplish only rows that have at least one zero. Try cbind(which(x),x) and you get zero counts in all rows